# LESS: Mixin with optional parameter

Tags: less, mixins

I have a LESS mixin with this code:

```
.generated_width (@margins:40px)
{
  -webkit-width:calc(~"100% - " @margins );
     -moz-width:calc(~"100% - " @margins );
          width:calc(~"100% - " @margins );
}
```

But sometimes I need to OPTIONALLY specify a % width different, for example "50%". Obviously, I could create another specific, but different, mixin with "50%" replacing "100%", but I prefer to pass this value as a parameter.

Is there a way to edit my mixin in order to OPTIONALLY accept a parameter that overrides default value of "100%" ? In other words, sometime the call could be:

```
.generated_width (40px)
```

Others

```
.generated_width (50%,40px)
```

Comment: Yea you just define another param that defaults to 100% and replace the 100% with that param

Comment: ok... I know could be a solution but is too rigid. If tomorrow I need "40%" ? ;-) For this reason I asked for an optional parameter, because 100% value is the most frequent one, but non the unique...

Comment: You don't get it, the param defaults to 100% but when you call it, you can take in different values

Comment: In fact putting `~""` just on the arithmetic op is enough, e.g.: `width: calc(@variable ~"-" @other-variable ~"+" @another-variable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have

```
.generated_width (@margins: 40px, @per: 100%)
{
  -webkit-width:calc(~"@{per} - " @margins );
     -moz-width:calc(~"@{per} - " @margins );
          width:calc(~"@{per} - " @margins );
}
```

When called

```
.generated_width (40px)
.generated_width (40px, 40%)
```

I think depending on your LESS version you can also do

```
.generated_width (@per:40%)
```

This way you can specify as many optional parameters as you want. This is much more flexible but a little bit more code to type. So if you only have 1 optional param then just leave it at the last spot

Comment: in this way.... @per parameter is simply OPTIONAL? So, to have an optional parameter, is enough to have it as last one?

Comment: It's the way I know how to do it

Comment: It OK except the `@per` variable inside quotes should be referred as `@{per}`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max ah yes you are right, I have corrected this

Comment: Hi Huangism: Your solution works perfectly but I tried tto update it replacing it with this one:

          `width:calc(@per ~" - " @margins );`

and equally works too. It seems also more intuitive, am I wrong? Is there a reason to prefer one instead of others? Thank you

Comment: @LucaDetomi go with the solution that you like better, after all it is you who will be looking at the code when debugging

Comment: Thank you Huangism, my doubt is only about "differences" between 2 approaches... maybe yours had an advantage that I did not see.... :-)